# Get all the values from excel file by using linqtoexcel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, linq-to-excel

I'm using `linqtoexcel` in my `asp.net mvc 4` project to read an excel file & get all the values from there. But I'm only getting the values of last row. Here are my codes,

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult ExcelRead()
    {
        string pathToExcelFile = ""
        + @"C:\MyFolder\ProjectFolder\sample.xlsx";

        string sheetName = "Sheet1";

        var excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(pathToExcelFile);
        var getData = from a in excelFile.Worksheet(sheetName) select a;

        foreach (var a in getData)
        {
            string getInfo = "Name: "+ a["Name"] +"; Amount: "+ a["Amount"] +">>   ";
            ViewBag.excelRead = getInfo;
        }
        return View();
    }
```

**View**

```
@ViewBag.excelRead
```

How can I get the values from all the rows? Need this help badly! Thanks.

Comment: here on foreach loop the Viewbag.excelRead is assigning the current row..thats why you are getting only last row in view..you should assign this to a list and call the list in the view

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me an example by code? I'm kinda noob in asp.net.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this (expanding on @Sachu's comment to the question) -

```
public ActionResult ExcelRead()
{
    string pathToExcelFile = ""
    + @"C:\MyFolder\ProjectFolder\sample.xlsx";

    string sheetName = "Sheet1";

    var excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(pathToExcelFile);
    var getData = from a in excelFile.Worksheet(sheetName) select a;
    string getInfo = String.Empty;

    foreach (var a in getData)
    {
        getInfo += "Name: "+ a["Name"] +"; Amount: "+ a["Amount"] +">>   ";

    }
    ViewBag.excelRead = getInfo;
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]` as `ViewBag.excelRead` value in view.

Comment: @SinOscuras, I have edited the code, check this one. I have removed the List<string> since, you are probably binding to a HTML div instead of looping on the result. You can do this way as well for brevity.

Comment: @Sin Oscuras, If you require line break between two rows of "Name..." then do add <br/> at the end of string.

Comment: Very nice workaround. Tnx a lot for your patience. This worked fine! :)

Comment: what is sheet name?

Answer (score 1):

Make the getDate as .ToList()

```
var getData = (from a in excelFile.Worksheet(sheetName) select a);
List<string> getInfo = new List<string>();

foreach (var a in getData)
{
    getInfo.Add("Name: "+ a["Name"] +"; Amount: "+ a["Amount"] +">>   ");

}
ViewBag.excelRead = getInfo;
return View();
```

Then pass this to the view
and do a foreach loop with @ViewBag.excelRead

```
    foreach (var data in @ViewBag.excelRead)
    {
    .....
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm getting `Compilation error` in view for `@model List<getData>`

Comment: `Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'getData' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78664/discussion-between-sachu-and-sin-oscuras).